# DotNet deployment process

Tags: asp.net, .net, jenkins, deployment, amazon-cloudfront

What is the best process of dotnet deployment?
Starting from Code checkin to Jenkins and to AWS server.

FYI: We have multiple AWS servers which sync via DFS. So, currently we are deploying only to 1 server and DFS sync it to other servers.

Few questions:

1. Should we recycle app pool after every deployment? Is is necessary?
2. What about packages? Should we checkin with code or restore them at build server?
3. What about T4 templates? Currently, we checkin the auto-generated code as well because without installing visual studio at build server we can't auto-generate T4 templates.
4. After few months we will be using webpacks as well.
5. This deployment is used to regenerate existing 10,000 pages which has Output cache enabled. Also, these 10,000 pages are behind AWS CloudFront. This deployment and 10,000 pages share the same app-pool. What happens to Output cache after deployment? Should we have a separate app-pool and why?

FYI:

- This deployment is only used for internal staff majorly. So, not much traffic to it.

Comment: Regarding T4 Templates, maybe you can have a look here:http://netitude.bc3tech.net/2013/06/15/t4-gotchyas-in-your-environment/